# getopt return unexpected value in cassandra shell

Tags: shell, cassandra

when I use cassandra shell to start Cassandra db, the getopt return unexpected values.

the command is : `getopt vfhp:bD:H:E: "$@"`, the input parameter is empty.

it returns strange values: `arena maxclass 4169728 --`.

when I run `getopt vfhp:bD:H:E:` in the shell alone, it returns normal value `--`

my system env is `3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP`

**Update**

This is a very strange issue, only happened with the cassandra script. I write one simple script to test

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -p ${!OPT@}
args=`getopt vfhp:bD:H:E: "$@"`
echo "args from input: $args"
```

It returns the normal result,

```
declare -- OPTERR="1"
declare -i OPTIND="1"
args from input:  --
```

About OPTERR and OPTIND, they are the same with in cassandra shell.

Comment: That sounds like cassandra is starting your shell with some arguments.

Comment: from the bash debug info, `$@`  is empty

Comment: From what debug info?

Comment: bash debug `bash -x`

Comment: And you see that line expand to `getopt vfhp:bD:H:E:`? If you add `declare -p ${!OPT@}` to the top of the script (above the `getopt` call) what does it output?